# Airflow - Send email Issue - How to specify sender email different than smtp_user

Tags: python, email, airflow

I have a SMTP server to enable alerting us if any DAG fail.

But I can't make it work (Airflow 2.7.1)

My assumption is that my smtp server requires a sender_email different than the login email while Airflow use smtp_user for the sender email aswell (but i might be wrong).

Here all I deed so far : I tested the SMTP server to send email using a simple python script and SMTPLIB (from the server) :

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

smtp_server = 'smtps.SERVER.SERVER'
smtp_port = 25
login_email = 'LOGIN@EMAIL.com'
sender_email = 'sender@email.com'
recipient_email = 'recipient_email@email.com'

message = MIMEText('This is a test email.')
message['Subject'] = 'Test Email'
message['From'] = sender_email
message['To'] = recipient_email

with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login_email, 'password')  # Replace 'password' with your actual password
    server.send_message(message)
```

This works well.

In airflow I have modified the airflow.cfg with the right parameters using the docker-compose file to set the parameters :

```
airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL: http://localhost:8080
      AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: "True"  # Expose Airflow configuration through the web interface
      AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_BACKEND: 'airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp'
      AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: 'SMTP_SERVER'  # SMTP Gateway FQDN
      AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: '25'                     # Port number
      AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS: 'True'              # TLS required
      AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL: 'False'                   # No SSL required
      AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: 'user_email@email.com'  # Service account login
      AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: 'PASSWORD'         # Password (provided separately)
      AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: 'email_from@email.com' # Sender email address   
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
```

I also set up a connection called smtp_default with those parameters.
The only thing I can't do in the connection is setting the sender_email different than the login email, I tried to modify extra to :

```
    {
  "extra__email__from": "noreply@example.com"
}
```

But does not work.

Here the error I get everytime, despite trying a lot of different things :

```
    [2024-02-09, 10:34:36 AEDT] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'smtp_default' for task execution.
[2024-02-09, 10:34:36 AEDT] {email.py:270} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2024-02-09, 10:34:36 AEDT] {EMAIL_TEST_TO_DELETE.py:42} ERROR - Error sending email: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
[2024-02-09, 10:34:36 AEDT] {taskinstance.py:1935} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 209, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/EMAIL_TEST_TO_DELETE.py", line 39, in send_email
    send_email_task.execute(context=None)  # Manually execute the task
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 77, in execute
    send_email(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 80, in send_email
    return backend(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 154, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, conn_id=conn_id, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 272, in send_mime_email
    smtp_conn = _get_smtp_connection(smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_timeout, smtp_ssl)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 317, in _get_smtp_connection
    return smtplib.SMTP(host=host, port=port, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 310, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
[2024-02-09, 10:34:36 AEDT] {taskinstance.py:1398} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=send_test_email, task_id=task_run_send_email, execution_date=20240208T233434, start_date=20240208T233435, end_date=20240208T233436
[2024-02-09, 10:34:36 AEDT] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1058 for task task_run_send_email ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address; 27244)
```

My dag :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import logging

# Configure the logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define the default arguments for the DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 2, 8),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
}

# Define the DAG
dag = DAG(
    'send_test_email',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple DAG to send a test email',
    schedule_interval=None  # This DAG does not run on a schedule
)

def send_email():
    try:
        logger.info("Attempting to send test email...")
        # Define the email task with the sender email address
        send_email_task = EmailOperator(
            task_id='send_email',
            to=['sifal.bekouche@suez.com'],
            subject='Test Email from Airflow',
            html_content='<p>This is a test email sent from Airflow.</p>',
            dag=dag
        )
        logger.info("Executing send_email_task...")
        send_email_task.execute(context=None)  # Manually execute the task
        logger.info("Email sent successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error sending email: {str(e)}")
        raise

# Define the PythonOperator
task_run_send_email = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task_run_send_email',
    python_callable=send_email,
    dag=dag,
)

# Set task dependencies
task_run_send_email
```

If you have any idea I'll be glad to hear it.

Thanks.